# Where Statement in DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm working on a database that already sends out two sales reports based on a date range that the user enters into a form. However, I'm attempting to add another report that will be output from a form based on the sales guys' ID. However, I'm having trouble figuring out where to put the where statement stating "WHERE TERRITORY=" & rs.fields(1) , which is what I need to make the specification equal to, if that makes sense. Here is my code. Any help with this is much appreciated.

**The line for FinalFormWithGauges is the one I'm specifically talking about

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim territory As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strSQL2 As String
Dim strSQL3 As String
Dim strQry As String
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Dim qdf2 As QueryDef
Dim dbs As Database
Dim i As Integer
Dim timestamp As String
DoCmd.OpenForm "Sales Email"
Forms![Sales Email]![FromDate].SetFocus

timestamp = Format(Forms![Sales Email]![FromDate].Value, "mm-yyyy")


Set rs = DBEngine(0)(0).OpenRecordset("KNOXLIVE_Engineers_Test")

For Each fld In rs.Fields
Do While Not rs.EOF
territory = rs.Fields(1)
Set dbs = CurrentDb
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM 001_SALES_OUTPUT_FOR_CURRENT_MONTH WHERE TERRITORY = """ & rs.Fields(1) & """"
strSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM CURRENT_OPEN_ORDERS WHERE TERRITORY = """ & rs.Fields(1) & """"
'strSQL3 = "SELECT * FROM FinalFormWithGauges WHERE TERRITORY = """ & rs.Fields(1) & """"
'MsgBox (strSQL)
Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("TheNewQueryDef", strSQL)
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "TheNewQueryDef", acFormatXLS, "\\cletus\data\accounting\Regional Sales Reporting\Monthly Sales Database Files By Month\Monthly Sales for " & territory & " " & timestamp & ".xls", False
CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete qdf.Name
Set qdf2 = dbs.CreateQueryDef("TheNewQueryDef", strSQL2)
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "TheNewQueryDef", acFormatXLS, "\\cletus\data\accounting\Regional Sales Reporting\Monthly Sales Database Files By Month\Current Open Orders for " & territory & " " & timestamp & ".xls", False
CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete qdf.Name
'Set gdf3 = dbs.CreateQueryDef("TheNewQueryDef", strSQL3)
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "FinalFormWithGauges", acFormatPDF, "\\cletus\data\accounting\Regional Sales Reporting\Monthly Sales Database Files By Month\Actual Sales vs Budget for " & territory & " " & timestamp & ".PDF", False**
'CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete qdf.Name
```

Comment: Based on 'the sales guy ID' or based on 'the territory'? If you enable the MSGBOX to display strSQL and add another MSBBOX to display strSQL2 is the syntax correct? If not, examine why, or update this question with the incorrect SQL and explain what is in 'rs.Fields(1)'

Comment: rs.fields(1) contains the sales guys id's in the master engineer table (sorry for the confusion, territory is their ID). Also, it isn't the SQL that's wrong, the SQL returns the correct information from the form, it just loses all of the form's formatting (as in the colors, header, etc..). It also causes the gauge images I have in one of the columns that represent how well the sales guys' did with sales this month to appear just as "bitmap image" instead of the actual image itself. I need to be able to have basically a where statement somehow saying send out this form where territory = xxx.

Comment: I see you opened a new question regarding this code? Your code sample needs to be corrected to close the two open loops you have (For Each and Do While). Your code is incorrect because you think you loop thru EVERY field in RS, yet you never reference any but the first field (rs.Fields(1)). No idea what other fields are in rs, but if you need each, then use 'rs.Fields(fld.name)'. What field in RS is Territory? 1, 2, 3...? Using field NAMES is a lot clearer for those trying to help.